# I need to change this existence check to use a wildcard on User::FileName

Tags: c#, ssis

I received some wonderful assistance from billinkc a few months back on a file existence check within a SSIS package.  Works very well, but I need to do the same thing with a wildcard.  Can billinkc or anyone else help revise this to do the existence check in User::FilePath where filename LIKE *DoR ?

```
public void Main()
  {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString());
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::FileExists"].Value = true;
        }


        // Log the state of all our SSIS variables
        bool fireAgain = false;
        string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
        foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
        }

        // Log the file path that was built
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, "local", "filepath", filepath), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

  }
```

Comment: Not sure why this had [tag:vbscript] in the tags, have removed it.

Comment: I just posted the logic I have because it is an existence check and works great.  But I  copied vbscript because I am welcome to other suggestions as well.

Comment: That is not how tags work, they are there to signal to those answering questions what the question is about and in this instance it’s clearly [tag:c#]. You don’t use them as wish-list we are not here to write code for you in a preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify your code to:

```
Dts.Variables["User::FileExists"].Value = 
   System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString()
           , "*[your wild card file name]").Any();
```

I believe that you need to switch to .Net Framework 4. You can do this by changing the Project Properties. Right click on the long undecipherable name on tin the solution explorer and click properties.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, KeithL.  Do I simply replace this?                               if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::FileExists"].Value = true;
        }

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't post it code style in my comment.  But I just want to know how exactly to input your suggestion, KeithL.  Please.

Comment: I've tried it, but am failing to compile with this error:                                                          
                                                        
                                                        
'IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extention method 'Any' accepting a frist argument type of 'IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @sqldba - you are probably using an old framework like 2.0 or 3.5. Change it to 4 or greater. I edited my answer.

Comment: Have gone into the solution properties and it currently says .NET Framework  4.7.  I must run, but I will be back later and will provide an update asap.